# Who did Rick Grimes shoot at the end of the Season 5 finale?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Clearly, Rick Grimes was asked to shoot someone at the end of the season 5 finale of *The Walking Dead*.  I was unable to tell from the angle who it was that he shot, although it seems as though he was turned slightly more towards his right.

Did I miss something?  Was it discussed during Talking Dead after the episode aired?

Comment: Nice spoiler in the Hot network questions list.

Comment: @JiK - Notice how I didn't say **who** he shot, or who were even the potential targets?  ;o)  I even edited the answer so it was displayed invisible since it contained more detailed spoilers.

Comment: In the talking dead they played a montage of peopl who died in the episode....both men were depicted as having died.

Comment: Well I was watching and at the time I thought he shot Pete, but when I replayed the scene I then thought he shot Reg, If I was Diana I would've had a smirk on my face when she told Rick to shoot Pete, but I'm not too sure... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From USA Today's ["The 5 most shocking moments in the 'Walking Dead' season finale"](http://entertainthis.usatoday.com/2015/03/29/the-5-most-shocking-moments-in-the-walking-dead-season-finale/):

> But it turns out wife-beater Pete just had to come after Rick with Michonne’s discarded sword, and ends up slitting the throat of Deanna’s husband, who tried to calm him down. Deanna was, shall we say, a little upset with the whole situation, and ended up defying all her morals and all her rules and telling Rick to kill Pete right there and then. Rick complies (a little too happily, if you’re asking us) only it just happens to be the very moment that Aaron and Daryl return with Morgan. The look on Morgan’s face as he saw the blood-stained Rick shoot Pete point-blank was pretty heartbreaking, considering Morgan had been looking for the man Rick used to be, not the man he is now.

Thus: [Pete](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Pete_%28TV_Series%29).

Comment: Also, Rick was pointing with his gun from a fair distance, and Reg (who would be the only other possibility) was laying in the arms of Deanna. Rick would not have risked to injure Deanna with this shot.

Comment: The reason I was unsure was because there appeared to be a couple of people on top of Pete as well, and both of them were potential targets for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it was Pete. On the Talking Dead, although they didn't say who. Morgan was asked how he reacted to Rick executing. Chris then stopped as though he knew he just said something he shouldn't of.

Answer (score 0):

I vote Rick shot Reg.  He was going to turn anyway and Deanna knows this.  Also the trauma of killing Reg by slicing his throat may just be the incentive that that "porch dick" Pete needs to clean his act up.  Not that Rick will let him have Jess back.

Answer (score -1):

Most people (including my wife) seem to think that Rick clearly shot Dr. Pete, but that the producers just chose not to show it directly because it was perhaps just a bit too graphic.  I say "Bull Gronky!"  On this show, there is nothing that they love *better* than to graphically "show it".  Can you remember poor little Beth Greene?  I don't know who or what it was that Rick did indeed shoot, but I very much doubt that Dr. Pete would have been shot in the head or elsewhere without us being shown every minute detail.  How about Glenn on this same episode, who clearly must have died when multiple walkers fell upon him?  We didn't see him torn apart, so that means that he *must* have survived the scene.  On *this* show, if you are not shown indisputable, unsurvivable carnage... then there is a reason for it.

Comment: [Executive producer Gale Anne Hurd: "that's really what the goal was -- to top it off with Morgan arriving at a particularly inopportune time to see Rick executing Pete in cold blood."](http://www.zap2it.com/blogs/the_walking_dead_ep_season_6_fear_spinoff_negan_interview-2015-04) Also: [More than anything, the TV show seems to just be following the comic book storyline on this, with ... Pete getting the Pete treatment. Rick shot Pete in the comic and there are no real indications of the show changing that.](http://www.wetpaint.com/walking-dead/articles/2015-04-02-did-rick-kill-pete-reg)